# Prove that the unit circle, $S^1:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1\}$, Is a one-dimensional manifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Prove that the unit circle,

$$S^1:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1\}$$,

Is a one-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by using the following coordinate chars, known as stereographic projections, and completing the following steps.

a)Show that $U_N:=S^1$\ $\{(0,1)\}$ and $U_S:=S^{-1}$\ $\{(0,1)\}$ are open subsets of S^1. Here $(0,1)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is the north pole of $S^1$ and $(0,-1)$ is the south pole.

b) Find an explicit formula for the function $\psi_S:=U_S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that sends a point $(x,y)\in U_S$ to the horizontal coordinate obtained by the straight line that passes from the north pole through $(x,y)$ and intersectimg the line $y=-1$.

### My attempt

a)

Let $\gamma_1:\{S^1-\{0,1\}\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$
Be defined by: ?

Let $\gamma_2:\{S^1-\{0,-1\}\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ Be defined by: ?

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2=\{S^1-\{0,1\}\}$

Let $V\subset \mathbb{R}^2=\{S^1-\{0,-1\}\}$

$U\cup V=S^1$ so for $c\in U\cup V=S^1$, $c\in U$ or $c\in V$. If $c\in U$ then $\gamma_1(U)=\mathbb{R}$ and likewise if $c\in V$ then $\gamma_2(V)=\mathbb{R}$, which are both open in $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$

If my attempt for part a is right, how should i define the functions and why?

b) If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are diffeomorphisms then we know $S^1$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $1$. Now we have to show that they are invertable.

Define $\phi_1:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow U$ by?

Define $\phi_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow V$ by?

As long as $\gamma_1$ and $\phi_1$ are inverses and $\gamma_2$ and $\phi_2$ are inverses, then we proved that the unit circle is a smooth manifold of dimension $1$.

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend to be more careful with the notation $\{0,1\} \neq \{(0,1)\}$. Concerning your maps, have you tried to draw a simple picture? (Even though it is a good exercise to work out the explicit maps, I would also like to point out that using the characterization with a submersion is faster in this case.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**

For your first question (a), the openness follows from the definition of the induced topology on $S^1$.

Concerning your second question (b), the simplest way is to draw a picture and work out the explicit maps from there. I've sketched the situation below.
[image: stereographic projection from the circle]

Recall that the north pole is $N=(0,1)$, take any point $A$ on the circle and compute the coordinates of the intersection of $(NA)$ and the line $\{y=-1\}$.

Comment: Does my attempt make any sense (as far as to prove that it's a manifold of dimension $1$)?

How do I find the equation of the line $NA$?

Comment: Your attempt makes sense. In this basic case of the circle, simple geometry suffices. Choose a point $A=(x, y)$ on the circle, draw the line from the pole that intersects the real line on a point $P=(-1,p)$. If you consider the triangles PNO' (where O' is (-1,0)) and NAB (where B is the projection of A onto the y axis), Thales theorem gives you a formula for p.